# Vue app: Why won't axios wait to complete after resolving on result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, axios

I have a component that fetches data from an api and populates my boostrap-vue table with rows. The rows then have checkmarks that collects the id's of the rows and sends them to an api to delete them. The backend works perfectly fine. My goal is to call the api again, after the delete call, to get an updated set of data and re-render my table, but my second axios call seems to be firing before my component data can update.

So the basic sequence will be:

1. Fetch initial data
2. Send delete request for 1 or more rows
3. Fetch new data and update table

The problem is occuring between steps 2 and 3

I have tried resolving on the axios call for the delete and making the new axios call inside the `.then()` block

Initial load (ajax is just a wrapper object for an axios request)

```
ajax.get(url + queryOrder)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.fileData = response.data.queryResults;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
})
```

When rows are checked and delete button clicked

```
ajax.delete(this.deleteUrl, {data: payload})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("sent delete request.....")
    this.fileData = []; // array of objects to populate rows
    this.deleteFiles = [];
    this.closeModal();
    this.sendSortData();
});
```

and the `sendSortData()` function simply contains another axios request to fetch the updated data, which is the same as the initial load.

```
ajax.get(this.searchUrl + searchFieldsQuery)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.fileData = response.data.queryResults; // should contain updated data
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
      })
```

I have logged several values in each function, and can confirm the correct sequence is occurring, and have even checked server logs to confirm these are sent in the correct order. I have tried using async/await which is just syntactic sugar and gives the same result. I have verified that changing the prop value of fileData changes the child component table data, so I am not sure what else I'm doing wrong.

I also checked the network tab in chrome dev tools, looked at the data for initial and final requests, and confirmed that the deleted file is still present in the new data, however if I place break points in the chrome debugger, and inspect the value of the new response in `sendSortData()`, the deleted file is gone, and the page re-renders correctly. This is leading me to believe that the asynchronous nature of these axios calls are not working as intended. Of course if I refresh the page the deleted row is gone, but I'd like to re-render the component without refreshing. Should I place a `watch()` on the child prop? Should I use a lifecycle method? Also note that all these calls occur inside the same component. Any answers are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: 'I also checked the network tab in chrome dev tools, looked at the data for initial and final requests, and confirmed that the deleted file is still present in the new data,' If you are getting response with deleted files then file is not deleted check our backend or can you make sure that you have checked correct response?

Comment: Hi Dasun, I have confirmed the file was actually deleted from the backend, since it returns success message and have also checked server logs. Also if I refresh the page, the file is deleted from the table since the component is updated, but I'm trying to update the component without refreshing.

Comment: I believe the reason the file is still there in the second request, is because it returns before the delete gets a chance to finish, but I'm not sure. I do know for sure that the api works fine and deletes the file.

Comment: Ok. Can you check  the response which you try to fetch the updated data after delete? And make sure your deleted files is not there. Then only we can assume there is a wrong in the code. Also did you try sending above request after timeout. Can you check those two points?

Comment: I did check the second response and the deleted file is still present, but as I mentioned if you put it through the debugger which pauses the execution, the deleted file is gone on the second request, which is correct. Also I used a setTimeout for a temporary fix, but this is not a good solution and doesn't produce consistent results. Do you know how to make sure the delete request finishes before sending another request?

Comment: Try using `setTimeout()` function. It's just a quick hack that I use. It's not a permanent solution though.

Comment: Yes. time out is not a solution. what i am saying is first we need understand what is happening, for that put a timeout and check whether you are getting u expected behavior. if so, we can assume that when fetch request going to the server file is not deleted it is being delete. that mean file is still available.

Comment: You are sending a response for the delete request right?  can you wait for delete the file before sending that response. It will solve this issue I guess. (Sorry about my English)

Comment: I used setTimeout while experimenting with 1, 2, and 3 seconds, but it will not consistently re render if you select more than 1 row. Also it is bad UX to have it sitting there for an arbitrary number of seconds before re-rendering. 

I am certainly sending the delete request before the second get request, my console logs in the UI confirm this, and I have also checked server logs and confirmed they are hitting the server in the correct order. The only time the re-rendering works as intended is when using the debugger, which pauses execution at each step.

Comment: I am not asking you to put timeout as solution. U said u tested with 3 second. Did it work correctly? bdw 'but it will not consistently re render if you select more than 1 row' what did you mean by this?  Did you try what i suggested above comment ?  'sending response after confirmed that file has been deleted'